# tabulation spacing

Tags: html, xhtml

is there an equivalent to the consoles special char '\t' in html ?

Comment: How would you define 'equivalent' in that case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use tables for table data.

There is no standard way to tabulate data without a table (either a real table using <table> or faking it with CSS `display`).

Comment: Where did he mention tabular data?

Comment: @Sampson, What thing other than data could he tabulate?

Comment: He means like the space before a paragraph.

Answer (score 31):

i'm using *"&*emsp;" looks better than *"&*nbsp;*&*nbsp;"

Answer (score 11):

You could use CSS's `text-indent` rule to apply a pre-defined indentation to the first line of a textblock.

```
<p style="text-indent:20px;">Hello World. I'm indented 20px.</p>
```

Answer (score 10):

Inside the **<pre>** tags you can use &#9; which is the unicode symbol of tabulation. But outside preformated section browser will show it as a space.

Answer (score 4):

Not that I know of, I usually use &nbsp; or pre elements.

Answer (score 4):

Other than relying on non breaking spaces, you can use a literal tab character inside of pre element, or by specifying white-space:pre as such:

```
<p id="foo">tab     between</p>
<style>
p#foo {
    white-space:pre;
}
```

Comment: That depends on browser behaviour, sadly.

Comment: @strager: What browser behaviour does it depend on?

Answer (score 2):

I needed to tabulate a simple listing in html and used CSS to 'fake it', here is the code:

```
/*CSS classes*/
.text-tabs-1{float:left;}

.text-tabs-2{
    float:left;
    margin-left:190px;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}

.clearer{clear:both;}

<!--HTML-->

<p>
<span class="text-tabs-1"><strong>Some text</strong>:</span><span class="text-tabs-2">Some indented text.</span><br />
<span class="text-tabs-1"><strong>Some text</strong>:</span><span class="text-tabs-2">Some indented text.</span><br />
<span class="text-tabs-1"><strong>Some text</strong>:</span><span class="text-tabs-2">Some indented text.</span><br />
<span class="text-tabs-1"><strong>Some text</strong>:</span><span class="text-tabs-2">Some indented text.</span><br />
</p>

<div class="clearer"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<p style="margin-left:2em"></p>`

Answer (score 0):

i'am using that "pattern" for convert plain text to simple HTML output:

```
someString.toString().replaceAll("\r\n", "\n").replaceAll("\n", "\n<BR>\n").replaceAll("\t", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;")
```

where "someString" is the source string we need to convert...

first... we convert all "\r\n" to "\n" (for Win and *nix format supporting), then converting "\n" and "\t" to HTML-like output

Answer (score -1):

if what you need is different levels of tabulation use list, and set the style: "list-style-type:none"
[www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code `&#8287;` to add a space in the html. For tab space use it 5 times or more.[Check here: https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/tryit.asp?deci=8287&ent=ThickSpace](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/tryit.asp?deci=8287&ent=ThickSpace)

Answer (score -3):

It is used for other purposes (so we have to be aware of this) but a tab like space is shown in the terms and descriptions tags.

For instance here:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Coffee</dt>
  <dd>Black hot drink</dd>
  <dt>Milk</dt>
  <dd>White cold drink</dd>
</dl>
```

the code is shown as

> Coffee
>
> (space) Black hot drink
>
> Milk
>
> (space) White cold drink

So, if you need only one tab, you can fake html by using `<dd>` tag.
The use of `<dd>` is another, as said,

> HTML `<dd>` Tag A description list, with terms and descriptions:
>   [more information](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dd.asp)

but it works :D
(only used once).

Comment: If the link breaks this answer wont be useful, bring the answer into the answer not just a link